# Scroll bar not visible for first time in 4.4 Kitkat : Cordova Mobile App

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, bootstrap-modal, w3.css

I am working on `cordova` mobile app using `jQuery` Mobile. I am facing one issue in it. I have several scroll-able div with scroll bar. For first time, the scroll bar is not visible. But if I navigate to another screen and comes back to this, then it's getting visible.This issue is observed with Android OS version i.e., on 4.4 - `Kitkat`.

Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: Can you share screenshot ? or some visual reference

Comment: What plugins, if any, do you have installed?